# Modifying the jqGrid editurl

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I've been battling some unfamiliar jqGrid code and I'm hoping someone with more insight can move me toward where I need to be in far less time than it's taken me to get nowhere.

I have a grid displaying registration info. When I click on a row, a **Refund** button appears. If I click that, a request is sent to the url defined in the grid's `editurl` property. That much I think I understand reasonably well. Maybe. Anyway, I need to capture that **Refund** click in order to launch a dialog (maybe a `confirm()` box) and modify the `editurl` with the return value before it's sent.

The existing column as defined in `colModel` looks like this:

```
{ name:'options',sortable:'false',width:60,editable:true,edittype:'button',
  editoptions:{
    value:'Refund', 
    dataEvents:[{
      type:'click',
      fn: function(e){ 
        jQuery('#registrationsTable').jqGrid('saveRow',lastRegistrationSelected,showStatus);
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

Any insight would be appreciated. I'm getting completely bogged down in the docs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you can just use

```
jQuery('#registrationsTable').jqGrid('saveRow',lastRegistrationSelected,showStatus,
                                     anyUrl);
```

instead of

```
jQuery('#registrationsTable').jqGrid('saveRow',lastRegistrationSelected,showStatus);
```

Look at the possible parameters of the [saveRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#saverow) method. In you need an additional conformation dialog you can insert it before the call of `saveRow` method.

Comment: Thanks, Oleg. I've definitely struggled to find my way through the docs, but you were on the nose and it worked perfectly. I appreciate the assist.